# react router dom and rendering internal component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

So, I'm having a simple routing which looks as the following:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import MainWindow from './components/MainWindow';
import { BrowserRouter, Outlet, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Settings from './components/Settings';
import { Dashboard } from '@mui/icons-material';
import Issue from './components/Issue';
import CreateIssueTool from './components/CreateIssueTool';
import Form from './components/Form';

function App() {

  return (
    <>
      <div className="App" style={{ height: "100%" }}>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<MainWindow />} />
          <Route path='settings/:id' element={<Settings />} />
          <Route path='dashboard/:id' element={<Dashboard />} />
          {/* for issue need to add it's id */}
          <Route path='issue' element={<Issue />} />
          <Route path='createissue' element={<CreateIssueTool />} >

          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

now, when I'm entering the CreateIssueTool's route at http://localhost:3001/createissue,
I'm trying to render within CreateIssueTool's component an internal component:

```
type Props = {}
function CreateIssueTool({ }: Props) {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Create Issue Tool</h1>
      <Form/>   
      <Button>cancel</Button>
      <Button>approve</Button>
    </>
  )
}

export default CreateIssueTool
```

provides me the following errors (I'll provide the shortened version of them to avoid a big messy message, will add them in their original form in the bottom:

```
> Uncaught Error: useSubmitImpl must be used within a data router.  See
> https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/picking-a-router.


> The above error occurred in the <ForwardRef> component:
>at http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:56301:7
>at Form
>at CreateIssueTool (http://localhost:3001/main.06c0f2a1fa7fd3f7c661.hot-update.js:34:7)
>at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:57372:5)
>at Routes (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:57794:5)
>at div
>at App
>at Router (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:57732:15)
>at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:56090:5)
```

Form:

```
import { Typography } from '@mui/material'
import { Stack } from '@mui/system'
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import React from 'react'
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const Form = () => {
  // const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm();

  return (
    <Stack>

      <Typography>Testinasdkaskdasdkasjdaskjdajsjkdag</Typography>
    </Stack>
  )
}

export default Form
```

index:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter, createBrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import MainWindow from './components/MainWindow';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);

root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
reportWebVitals();
```

I'm a bit confused regarding the Routing process, why would it be affected by the Form component within the CreateIssueTool component?

What would be the right approach to allow such internal rendering?

Regards

Comment: The error obvious from the code you're using. The error is telling you that the `Form` component is using one of the new RRDv6.4 hooks that requires a route rendered by a data router, and your code isn't using a data router. It seems you are using a regular `BrowserRouter`. Can you edit the post to include all relevant code you are working with (*the router, the `Form` component, etc*) as part of a complete [mcve]?

Comment: Added Form and index components, as well as imports of App.

Comment: Can you share the complete file code for the `CreateIssueTool` component? I don't see where you are using the [`useSubmitImpl` hook](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router-dom/index.tsx#L604) and I suspect you've mixed up some imports and accidentally imported the `Form` component from `react-router-dom` instead of your component.

Comment: sure. sorry for the back&forth. added.

Comment: found the issue. you were correct, it had something to do with the imports. the 'Form' was imported for some odd reason from react router, which is obviously not my intention. thanks !

Comment: Ok, cool. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.